# Proving an equivalence relation from partitions

Tags: set-theory

Equivalence relations from partitions
A set S is given as a union $S=\bigcup_{i} S_i$
of mutually disjoint subsets $S_i$. Define a relation on S by declaring $s,\tilde{s} \in S$ as related if they are contained in the same subset $S_i$. Show that this is an equivalence relation, which partitions
S into the subsets $S_i$.

Could I get some advice or hints on how to start and understand what the problem is asking?

Comment: Not a site for homework, besides have you tried to use the definitions? It's direct

Comment: it's just straightforward definition checking really.

Comment: It will not necessarily be a partition unless one assumes all subsets $S_i$ are nonempty.

Comment: @coffemath: At least some definitions of "partition" include nonemptiness of the partitioning subsets.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set